# Modifying a mesh's vertices with vertex shader doesn't change its BufferGeometry attributes and causes raycaster to be inaccurate

Tags: three.js

[Updated with a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9q3fwbk1/5/)]
If you hover slightly outside the plane the raycaster still thinks it's hovering over the object because we modified the z position in the vertex shader

For my project I have a carousel of planes (PlaneBufferGeometry and ShaderMaterial) that I need hover effects on.

However, I have this one state where the planes are shrunk by animating each vertex's `z` coordinate in the vertex shader. In this state, my hover effects using THREE.Raycaster are broken because the positions in the BufferGeom array aren't updated so the Raycaster still uses the same uvs as the original sized planes.

I already tried calling the following functions for every plane `p` after the vertex shader runs:

```
p.frustrumCulled = false;
p.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
p.geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
p.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
p.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
p.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
p.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
p.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
```

I also know if I just scale each plane using `THREE.Mesh`'s built in `scale`, the uvs would be raycasted correctly but I can't do that because there's a specific animation I can only achieve with the vertex shader.

Comment: Please demonstrate the issue with a simple [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/). BTW: `verticesNeedUpdate` and `normalsNeedUpdate` are no properties of `BufferGeometry`. Besides, calling `computeFaceNormals()` has also no effect since the method is only there for backwards compatibility. Setting `frustrumCulled` to false does not affect raycasting.

Comment: @Mugen87 here's a quick fiddle to demonstrate it https://jsfiddle.net/9q3fwbk1/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raycasting happens on the CPU. If you are going to displace vertices on the GPU (via the vertex shader), raycasting can' work correctly since it is not possible to respect the transformed vertices for the intersection test.

You have two options now. You can apply the transformation at the CPU instead of the GPU before performing the raycast. An other option is the usage of different approaches like GPU picking in order to detect the interaction with a 3D object.